# updating MySQL 5.6.40 DD with liquibase in AWS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-rds, liquibase

I have just created a DB MySQL 5.6.40 in AWS. I can connect to the DB using Sequel Pro 1.1.2

this is my configuration in the pom.xml file:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
  <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.5.3</version>
  <configuration>
    <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/datamodel/liquibaseChangeLog.xml</changeLogFile>
    <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
    <url>pradera.cwob2oxhu1so.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com</url>
    <username>pradera</username>
    <password>AzSWMdlckdstgs0aed</password>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>process-resources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>updateSQL</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.27</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

but when I run `mvn clean package -DskipTests`

I got this error:

> ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.5.3:updateSQL (default) on project icrypts: Error setting up or running Liquibase: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Connection could not be created to pradera.cwob2oxhu1so.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com with driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.  Possibly the wrong driver for the given database URL -> [Help 1]
>       [ERROR]

Comment: I hope that is not the real user and password you posted there ...

Comment: no, thanks :-) it is not

Comment: Can you connect to the database with a DB tool and a JDBC driver? Liquibase uses JDBC. So maybe it helps to try to connect to the DB with something else that uses JDBC just to make sure that the connection generally works.

Comment: The url doesn't look like a JDBC url. Shouldn't it be like `jdbc:mysql://pradera.cwob2oxhu1so.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `pradera.cwob2oxhu1so.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com` for `jdbc:mysql://pradera.cwob2oxhu1so.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com`